# How would this JavaScript be refactored to remove the 'with' statement

Tags: javascript, refactoring, with-statement

Here is the JS of a simple clock app. <strike>In JS, the 'with' statements are no longer used.</strike> I would like help understanding how to keep the functionality while removing the use of the 'with' statement. Thank you.

```
function moveHands() {
  with (new Date()) {
    h = 30 * (getHours() % 12 + getMinutes() / 60); // 30 degrees for each hour
    m = 6 * (getMinutes()); // 6 degrees each minute
    s = 6 * (getSeconds()); 
    // now rotate the clock via changing css

    document.getElementById('hours').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + h + "deg);";
    document.getElementById('minutes').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + m + "deg);";
    document.getElementById('seconds').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + s + "deg);";

    setTimeout(moveHands, 1000);
  }
}
window.onload = moveHands;
```

Comment: `var d = new Date();` ..... `d.getHours()` .... etc

Comment: *with* is not deprecated, it's in the current version of [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-with-statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN `with` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with):

> Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict
>   mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose
>   properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

Basically, that just means you have to assign the object to a variable before using it, which is pretty standard.
So in your case, your code should look like this:

```
function moveHands() {
  var date =  new Date();
    h = 30 * (date.getHours() % 12 + date.getMinutes() / 60); // 30 degrees for each hour
    m = 6 * (date.getMinutes()); // 6 degrees each minute
    s = 6 * (date.getSeconds()); 
    // now rotate the clock via changing css

    document.getElementById('hours').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + h + "deg);";
    document.getElementById('minutes').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + m + "deg);";
    document.getElementById('seconds').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + s + "deg);";

    setTimeout(moveHands, 1000);

}

window.onload = moveHands;
```

Comment: `From the MDN with documentation` - I'd say the OP is fully aware of that :p

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the date to a variable, then explicitly call the date methods on that variable.

```
function moveHands() {
  var currentDate = new Date();

  h = 30 * (currentDate.getHours() % 12 + currentDate.getMinutes() / 60); // 30 degrees for each hour
  m = 6 * (currentDate.getMinutes()); // 6 degrees each minute
  s = 6 * (currentDate.getSeconds()); 
  // now rotate the clock via changing css

  document.getElementById('hours').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + h + "deg);";
  document.getElementById('minutes').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + m + "deg);";
  document.getElementById('seconds').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + s + "deg);";

  setTimeout(moveHands, 1000);
}
window.onload = moveHands;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a local variable.

```
function moveHands() {
  var date = new Date();
  h = 30 * (date.getHours() % 12 + date.getMinutes() / 60); // 30 degrees for each hour
  m = 6 * (date.getMinutes()); // 6 degrees each minute
  s = 6 * (date.getSeconds()); 
  // now rotate the clock via changing css

  document.getElementById('hours').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + h + "deg);";
  document.getElementById('minutes').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + m + "deg);";
  document.getElementById('seconds').style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + s + "deg);";

  setTimeout(moveHands, 1000);
}
window.onload = moveHands;
```